# How to properly make a callback to create a model, after initialize of another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, callback

*To start, I may be using the wrong callback for what I'm trying to do*

*and/or there may be a better "Rails Way" to accomplish this. If so, I'm all ears.*

I've been referencing [api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/ClassMethods](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_save)

and

[guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#creating-an-object](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#creating-an-object)

I need to implement:

"user sign up creates an account associated with user as owner"

(ultimately, user will belong_to account, and account will has_many users)

Accounts in database schema have name:string and owner_id:integer

Currently, I'm not able to access the newly created User, and the Account is not being created. I think I'm very close though.

current `models/user.rb`:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_save :create_account
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable


  private

  def create_account
    Account.create(owner_id: user.id, name: "#{user.name}'s Account")
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

outputs to the stacktrace:

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2022-02-04 23:39:40 -0600
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"name"=>"tester", "phonenumber"=>"1234567890", "email"=>"test@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists? (1.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "test@test.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "reset_password_token", "reset_password_sent_at", "remember_created_at", "created_at", "updated_at", "name", "phonenumber") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "test@test.com"], ["encrypted_password", "[FILTERED]"], ["reset_password_token", "[FILTERED]"], ["reset_password_sent_at", "[FILTERED]"], ["remember_created_at", nil], ["created_at", "2022-02-05 05:39:40.493526"], ["updated_at", "2022-02-05 05:39:40.493526"], ["name", "tester"], ["phonenumber", "1234567890"]]
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 298ms (ActiveRecord: 2.1ms | Allocations: 9928)



NameError (undefined local variable or method `user' for #<User id: nil, email: "test@test.com", created_at: "2022-02-05 05:39:40.493526000 +0000", updated_at: "2022-02-05 05:39:40.493526000 +0000", name: "tester", phonenumber: "1234567890">
Did you mean?  super):

app/models/user.rb:12:in `create_account'
```

Comment: `user` variable not defined. since it is inside the model you can use directly use the attributes of the object. 

Account.create(owner_id: id, name: "#{name}'s Account")

Comment: Thank you so much, that exactly what was my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As prasannaboga already wrote in his comment. Callbacks like these are running in the context of an instance. That means you do not need to call a specific `user` first because the current object is already that user.

Additionally, in the context of a model, the `redirect_to` call doesn't make any sense. Models don't know anything about requests and responses. `redirect_to` is a controller method and you need to add it to your controller.

The following callback method should work:

def create_account
Account.create(owner_id: id, name: "#{name}'s Account")
end

I wonder why you decided to not add an `has_one :account` or `has_many :accounts` association to your `User` model? By doing so you could simplify the method even more because then Rails would handle setting the `id` automatically, like this

```
build_account(name: "#{name}'s Account")  # when `has_one` or
accounts.build(name: "#{name}'s Account") # when `has_many`
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, that makes sense. as soon as i fixed the parameters I only needed to remove the redirect_to just as you said. Specifying `has_many :users` to account model and `belongs_to :account` on the user model is my next step; am I correct in thinking that will also require database migrations that say those columns reference each other? my CTO suggested we might be able to keep the logic within the models and controllers for more changeability, without a strict `:references` migration specification.

Comment: Because you already have an `owner_id` in the database there is no additional migration needed when using `belongs_to` and `has_many`. You just need to configure those associations in a way that they use this column instead of a column that follows the Rails naming conventions. Account `belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :owner_id` and User `has_many :accounts, foreign_key: :owner_id` should work.